# Node-RED connection to Waze

Tags: node-red, waze

I am trying to use the http request node to get the route between 2 points using the following url (replace xxxxx with actual coordinates):

https://www.waze.com/row-RoutingManager/routingRequest?from=x:-34.xxxxx+y:-58.xxxxx&to=x:-34.xxxxx+y:-58.xxxxx&at=0&returnJSON=true&returnGeometries=false&returnInstructions=false&timeout=60000&nPaths=1&clientVersion=4.0.0&options=AVOID_TRAILS:t,ALLOW_UTURNS:t

I found that this is the url that I need to use in a lot of references, but this url throws always the error "403 Forbidden", no matter if I use it in Node-RED, Chrome, Firefox or IExplorer.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure Waze offers this as a public API? I would guess this requires a authentication cookie/token and possibly the correct referer header

Comment: Have you checked out https://developers.google.com/waze/ ?
This problem is also not node-red specific so it is better to change the title of this question and remove the node-red tag.